# Is there any way to use skype app on windows 8.1 without signing in to Microsoft Account?

Tags: skype-metro

There is a skype app on Windows 8.1 Pre Installed.If I want to use it windows asks to sign in Microsoft Account.Is there any way to use skype app on windows 8.1 without signing in to Microsoft Account?

Comment: Unless you already have a Skype account, the answer to your question is, no its not possible.  Microsoft retire Skype accounts about a year ago.  I should add you don't have to link your Windows account to Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have used Windows 8 personally but on reviewing what the support for Skype has to say and based on FAQs, I believe in order to use the Skype which was pre-installed on Windows 8, you will need a Microsoft Account.

Check the FAQs here > https://support.skype.com/en/category/WINDOWS8/

If you do not want to register for the Microsoft Account, you can download the desktop application of Skype suggested by gladiator2345

This reminds of the time where Google and Youtube got togther. Now you have to have a Google+ account in order to comment on Youtube and such. However, I do not mind Google+